# How to watch state variables in redux-toolkit?

Tags: javascript, redux-toolkit

When I stop at a breakpoint inside the reducer and try to watch variables inside the state, I can only see Proxy, how can I see the actual contents of my state?

[image: state]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since RTK uses [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) internally, the state obtained in the reducer is the draft state of Immer. If you want to get the state in the form of a JS plain object, you need to use the [current](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/current/) method provided by Immer.

> This can be very useful for debugging purposes (as those objects won't be Proxy objects and not be logged as such)

See RTK [other-exports#current](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#current)

> The `current` function from the `immer` library, which takes a snapshot of the current state of a draft and finalizes it (but without freezing). Current is a great utility to print the current state during debugging, and the output of `current` can also be safely leaked outside the producer.

Also, see [Logging Draft State Values](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#logging-draft-state-values)

> It's very common for a developer to call `console.log(state)` during the development process. However, browsers display Proxies in a format that is hard to read, which can make console logging of Immer-based state difficult.

When using either `createSlice` or `createReducer`, you may use the current utility that we re-export from the `immer` library. This utility creates a separate plain copy of the current Immer `Draft` state value, which can then be logged for viewing as normal.

E.g.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@reduxjs/toolkit@1.6.1/dist/redux-toolkit.umd.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            const { configureStore, createSlice, current } = window.RTK;

            const counterSlice = createSlice({
                name: 'user',
                initialState: { value: 0 },
                reducers: {
                    increment(state) {
                        console.log('immer draft state: ', state)
                        console.log('js object state: ', current(state))
                        state.value++;
                    },
                },
            });

            const store = configureStore({ reducer: counterSlice.reducer });
            store.dispatch(counterSlice.actions.increment());

        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Output:

[image]